# Implementing Oauth2.0 flow in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an IOS SDK and implementing oauth2.0 flow.

I have the following oauth2.0 flow in the IOS SDK to allow developers to get control of my users' accounts:

- Open up webview with mysite/oauth2.0 as url
- User logs in/registers.
- Mysite.com redirects to special url with a code or error in the query string.
- Webview (via the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function) recognizes special url and closes itself.

It then passes the code to the parent controller's delegate function.

```
[self.delegate processOauth2.0Code: code]
```

If there is an error (maybe user denied the oauth2.0), it creates NSError object and sends the NSError object to a separate delegate function)

```
[self.delegate processOAuth2.0Error: error]
```

- Parent controller function then sends the code to a web server
- Web server uses the code with their application key to make an api call to my site to retrieve access token.

Is that how such Oauth2.0 flows are designed in a mobile app?

Do you guys have any advice for me on improving the design?

Is it normal to have two delegate functions for code and error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above process looks correct, however I'm not familiar with all of the nitty-gritty details. The reason for this is that there are lots of OAuth2 libraries that allow you to treat this process as essentially a black-box.

**Popular OAuth Providers:**

- Lots of folks use AFNetworking with its OAUth exentensions.
- I use GTMOAuth2, which can be installed via [CocaoPods](http://www.cocoapods.org). It contains methods for both authentication (ie obtaining, validating or refreshing a token), as well as sending network requests. I just use it for the authentication part, using another HTTP stack, where I just add the OAuth token as a request header.

**To use GTMOAuth2:**

- It can be a little complicated to set up. A bit more code than would be suitable for an SO answer. Basically you add a GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch to your window, and use it to collect credentials.
- The best way to test it out is to run the examples, and then modify them to talk to your own back-end. Once you have that running, port the code into your app.

I recommend that you use an OAuth library rather than try to implement it all yourself.